# Build error when using both objective-c and swift libraries with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have an Objective C project which has a podfile like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'Linbik' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'
    pod 'DateTools', '~> 1.6.1'
    pod 'Sentry', :git => 'https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-swift.git', :tag => '2.1.3'
end
```

`DateTools` is an **Objective C** library, and `Sentry` is a **Swift** one.
If I remove `Sentry` pod and `use_frameworks!` line, and then run `pod install`, pods are correctly installed and project builds just fine.

But if I run `pod install` with the podfile above, pods are correctly installed but I can't build the project. It gives me an error like this:

```
'NSDate+DateTools.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

The import is done like this:

```
#import <NSDate+DateTools.h>
```

This is just part of the code that gives me an error. There are also some imports like this:

```
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
```

That gives the same error.

Xcode suggests me to use double quotes on import, but that doesn't help.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by deleting derived data.

Answer (score 1):

Change pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0' And use this

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0
pod 'DateTools', '~> 1.6.1'
pod 'Sentry', :git => 'https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-swift.git', :tag => '2.1.3'
```